# Google assistant is not working

Tags: windows, python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I am getting the below error after entring the "ENTER" key

The error I got is as below:

Press Enter to send a new request...
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "book".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hey Google".
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hey Google".
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
ERROR:root:Exception iterating requests!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\audio_helpers.py", line 338, in **iter**
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py", line 165, in consume_request_iterator
    request = next(request_iterator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 131, in iter_log_assist_requests
    for c in self.gen_assist_requests():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 217, in gen_assist_requests
    for data in self.conversation_stream:
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "hey Google".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 469, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in **call**
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 458, in main
    continue_conversation = assistant.assist()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tenacity__init__.py", line 241, in wrapped_f
    return self.call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tenacity__init__.py", line 330, in call
    start_time=start_time)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tenacity__init__.py", line 279, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.**get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tenacity__init**.py", line 333, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 139, in assist
    self.deadline):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py", line 341, in **next**
    return self._next()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\grpc_channel.py", line 324, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNKNOWN, Exception iterating requests!)>

Comment: What happens if you press the enter key and say "what time is it"?